# Password is not saved

Tags: python, html, django

The password is not saved in new user registration. I wrote in views.py

```
def regist(request):
    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'regist_form': regist_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/regist.html', context)

@require_POST
def regist_save(request):
    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if regist_form.is_valid():
        user = regist_form.save(commit=False)
        password = regist_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
        }
        return redirect('detail')

    context = {
        'regist_form': regist_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/regist.html', context)
```

in **regist.html**

```html
<div class="heading col-lg-6 col-md-12">             
        <h2>New account registration</h2>
    
        <form class="form-horizontal" action="regist_save/" method="POST">             
          <div class="form-group-lg">             
            <label for="id_username">username</label>
                         {{ regist_form.username }}             
          </div>                          
          <div class="form-group-lg">             
            <label for="id_email">email</label>
                          {{ regist_form.email }}
          </div>   
          <div class="form-group-lg">             
            <label for="id_password">password</label>             
             {{ regist_form.password1 }}             
          </div>                          
          <div class="form-group-lg">
            <label for="id_password">password（conformation）</label>             
             {{ regist_form.password2 }}
             <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.password2.help_text }}</p>             
          </div>                          
          <div class="form-group-lg">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">SUBMIT</button>             
            <input name="next" type="hidden"/>             
            </div>
          </div>
          {% csrf_token %}             
        </form>             
</div>
```

in **forms.py**

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email','password1','password1',)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

Username & email is registered normally. So I really cannot understand why the password is not registered. I read Django tutorial and I think my code is ok.

How should I fix this? What should I write it?

Comment: change `regist_form.cleaned_data.get('password')` to `regist_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form have fields `password1` and `password2` and not `password` and `regist_form.cleaned_data.get('password')` return None. 
So you should rename `password1` field to `password`:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email','password', 'password2',)
```

Comment: thx ur comments.I have 2 password filed because it is check to confirm　whether 1st ＆2nd password is same or not.I cannot understand your code can do my ideal sysgtem.Is it ok?

Comment: @user8504021 Two password fields is OK. I mean that your form dont have `password` field. But you trying to access it in the view: `password = regist_form.cleaned_data.get('password')`. This line will always return None. You can fix it by rename one of your Form field to `password` or just change view. Replace `password` with `password1`: `password = regist_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')`